# Autosuggest using Google Places

Tags: google-places-api

I am using the following code to get the Google Places Autosuggest working and I am not able to get this working(Autosuggest does not work). Please point what might be wrong:

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
<form action="">
  <input type="text" id="city"></form>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   var input = $("#city"); 
   var options = {
           types: ['(cities)'],
           componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}
};    
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autocomplete expects the 1st argument  to be an input-element, currently (I guess)it's a jQuery-object.

Use either:

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[0], options);
```

or

```
var autocomplete = 
  new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('city'), options);
```